# Spring Transactions - TransactionTimedOutException: Transaction timed out

Tags: java, spring, mybatis, spring-transactions

We are running Spring-Batch jobs against a DB2 database.  When running in Eclipse in a local scenario the individual transactions are taking longer and frequently timeout with the exception :

```
2016-10-26 14:48:07,685 [main] ERROR org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep - JobRepository failure forcing exit with unknown status
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionTimedOutException: Transaction timed out: deadline was Wed Oct 26 14:47:25 EDT 2016
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.ResourceHolderSupport.checkTransactionTimeout(ResourceHolderSupport.java:141)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.ResourceHolderSupport.getTimeToLiveInMillis(ResourceHolderSupport.java:130)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.ResourceHolderSupport.getTimeToLiveInSeconds(ResourceHolderSupport.java:114)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.applyTimeout(DataSourceUtils.java:275)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.applyStatementSettings(JdbcTemplate.java:1222)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:581)
```

I can provide the full stack trace, but it's quite large.  We use the following Components : 
- Spring 3.0.7 (Upgrade is not possible)
- org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource 
- MyBatis 3.1.1
- DB2

I've been trying to figure out how to increase the timeout on the Spring transaction Manager and/or Datasource, but I've only found one reference using the Spring tx:advice from Chapter 16 of the Spring Docs :

```
<tx:advice id="defaultTxAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="*" timeout="360"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

But this didn't do anything, the issue persists.  Is there any other settings I can try?  Either in the Datasource and/or MyBatis?

I couldn't find anything on a DB2 JDBC property.  And nothing on the org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.

The Spring XML configurations are :

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${datasource.jdbcDriver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${datasource.databaseUrl}" />
    <property name="username" value="${datasource.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${password:datasource}" /> 
    <property name="properties">
        <props>
            <prop key="oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout">5000</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

</bean>

<!-- ================================================================== -->
<!-- MyBatis Mapper Configuration                                       -->
<!-- ================================================================== --> 
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<tx:advice id="defaultTxAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="*" timeout="360"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

tia, adym

Comment: Are you running into deadlocks? Transactions should be as small as possible, is it maybe to big? Are you running the connection through an SSH tunnel? I found tunneling consume a serious amount of time.

Comment: Deadlocks is a possibility...I can test for that.  No tunneling though.  I did find out that the tx:advice timeout DOES appear to be working for the Spring piece, but something else appears to be timing out now...perhaps the DB2 JDBC driver, but I can't find a property to pass in the URL for that.